# Is it logical to search an array with 1500 objects?

Tags: swift, search

I'm working on an iOS application which needs to search about 1500 values(Airport Names).

Am I need to use a SQL server or simple txt file which is separated with ":".

For example:

> KJFK:John F Kennedy International Airport:New
>   York:USA:http://www.airport-jfk.com/

This is an example line. I'll have 1500 different copies of that.

Can I still use plain text files or will I need to use SQL structure?

Comment: 1500 values are nothing. You can easily read them up into memory and search them in memory. Once you have more data structures or more data, you can consider moving to Core Data.

Comment: Okay thank you. Please post it as an answer so I can mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1500 values are nothing. You can easily read them up into memory and search them in memory.

Once you have more data structures or more data, you can consider moving to Core Data.

Of course, you can also use a Core Data in memory store.

This is not a simple question and it has no simple answers. If you need to perform the search 20 times every second, 1000 values can be already too much. The problem has multiple variants and it will have multiple solutions.

The best advice is to implement the *simplest* solution and only modify it when you hit performance problems.